# No Boot Device found after reinstalling Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2

I got rid of my dual boot System because it caused only troubles. Now its only Ubuntu 17.10 that is installed on my Laptop. Somehow I seem to be very unlucky recently. The Laptop wont find the boot partition of Ubuntu. I can boot into the Live USB just fine.

I don't have UEFI.
Ubuntu Hard Drive Manager says, that my Drive is likely to fail soon.
So, the disc is either broken, or theres just something wrong with the bootloader. Hope someone can help.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.3 GiB, 1425731584 bytes, 2784632 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x856f268a

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 117186559 117184512  55.9G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       117188606 488396799 371208194   177G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       132812800 488396799 355584000 169.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       117188608 132812799  15624192   7.5G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Comment: If the drive is likely to fail soon then certainly it has problems, problems that were likely the cause of the "troubles with dual boot". Trying to install Ubuntu as th only OS won't repair the drive. Replace it and install what you want.

Comment: New disk solved the problem :)